# JS Slack Notification Filter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Utilizing Slack webhooks and webtask.io I've created a notification filter (based off of a generic script I found online) for Slack that, at this time, filters out messages that contain the string NON-SLA. I'm totally new to JS so getting to this point has all been trial and error. I would like to adjust the script to filter out messages that contain one of any number of strings, but I'm at a roadblock mostly because I'm not familiar with the language and have had 0 luck trying out the various solutions that I've found online.

Here's the current filter for just a single string:

```
function shouldNotify(data) {
  return !data.text.includes('NON-SLA');
}
```

This returns TRUE for shouldNotify and the rest of the script pushes the message to the specified channel.

I couldn't find a way to do something similar to this:

```
return !data.text.includes('one','two','three');
```

Looked into using an array, but nothing of what I found seemed like it would work with the existing script as a whole and I just simply do not have the time to attempt to rewrite it. Seems that this would be the most efficient and proper way to do it though.

Full script can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/christronyxyocum/16007adda01b8fe851732c573510f3de).

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as, again, I'm out of ideas with my limited knowledge of this.

TIA

Comment: Are you looking for `["one", "two", "three"].some(string => "one or two or three".includes(string))`?

Comment: Thanks, but as I'm not familiar with the language, I really don't know. I just tried:

    return !data.text.includes["110336", "103532", "103405"].some(string => "110336 or 103532 or 103405".includes(string))

But this did not work.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much! Sorry, I didn't realize this was just for functional code/scripts. Guess that explains the downvotes I got.

Comment: Yes, that's surely the reason for the downvotes. You can still voluntarily remove the question here though, as you didn't get any answers yet.

Comment: Looks like your code works in a test, but not on webtask.io

`"error": "Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode"`

Comment: Used var instead of let and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
function shouldNotify(data) {
  const string = ["one", "two", "three"];
  return !string.some(string => data.text.includes(string));
}

// Example:
console.log(shouldNotify({text: "four apples"})); // true
console.log(shouldNotify({text: "two oranges"})); // false
```

Instead of supplying an arrow function to `Array.some`, you could alternatively make use of `Function.bind` and write:

```
  return !string.some(String.includes.bind(string));
```

Comment: Used your provided answer, but had to replace let with var (can't use the const either) as webtask.io threw an error when I tried to use let.

Thanks so much for your help!